# MySQL dump, access denied 1045 with correct username and password

Tags: mysql

I have created a user callsed "backup" for my MySQL Database, and given it a specific password.[image]

and I'm now trying to execute this command:

```
sudo mysqldump --user=backup -password=SuperS3f@kePass --all-databases > all_databases.sql
```

resulting in these errors:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'backup'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

I have tried with the root mysql user, and without sudo as well, getting same error

MySQL version:
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22
on an Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably explained by this:

[Host wildcard does not match 'localhost'](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69570)

And that is related to the fact that for mysql connecting to `localhost` really means connecting to an UNIX socket (probably `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`), while connecting to `127.0.0.1` means connecting (using IPv4) to `localhost`. So they chose to distinguish their access rights.

To check this is the case, try again with:

```
sudo mysqldump  -h 127.0.0.1 --user=backup -password=SuperS3f@kePass --all-databases > all_databases.sql
```

Then correct the access rights (eg to `'backup'@'localhost'`) instead.